# Inserting a linked list compiler gives me an error, and debugger has different error. What should I do

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Compiler error :

```
PS C:\Users\khash\Desktop\C C++> cd "c:\Users\khash\Desktop\C C++\" ; if ($?) { gcc Untitled.c -o Untitled } ; if ($?) { .\Untitled }   
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file Untitled.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Debugger: Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, main () at C:\Users\khash\Desktop\C C++\Untitled.c:64
64  head = NULL;

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node *head;

void insert(int f)
{
    struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct Node)));
    temp -> data = f;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    struct Node *temp1 = head;
    while(temp1 -> next != NULL)
    {
        temp1 = temp1 -> next;
    }
    temp1 -> next = temp;

}
void print()
{
    struct Node *temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", temp -> data);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}
void deleted(int b)
{
    if(b == 1)
    {
        struct Node *temp3 = head;
        head = temp3 -> next;
        free(temp3);
        return;
    }

    struct Node* temp = head;

    for(int i = 0; i = b - 2; i++)
    {
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    struct Node* temp1 = temp -> next;
    temp -> next = temp1 -> next;
    free(temp1);
}

int main()
{
    head = NULL;
    insert(3);
    insert(4);
    insert(4);
    insert(2);
    insert(8);
    print();
    int b;
    printf("Enter pos of element");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    deleted(b);
    print();

}
```

Comment: "Permission denied" errors when writing the executable are usually the sign of one of these things: 1) The program is already running; 2) You don't have write-access to the directory; Or 3) Your anti-virus is medling. First of all make sure the program isn't already running. Use the task manager to check and terminate the program if needed.

Comment: I am wondering how does your debugger work but normal execution doesn't. Doesn't the debugger use the same executable?

Comment: BTW, about your bug it's probably this line inside `deleted()` - `struct Node *temp3 = head; head = temp3 -> next;`. If `head` is `NULL` then next line crashes.

Comment: Some general rule: If you are not able to compile your program, there is absolutely no point in running a debugger on it.

Comment: @kiner_shah maybe the debugger is the reason why the file is in use and it just keeps an old version open

Comment: I'm  new to debugging. I need to learn that basic function and stuff.

Comment: `head = temp;` followed immediately `free(temp);` will free `head`. Remove the `free` here.

Comment: @Gerhardh, yeah that's possible.

Comment: removing free (temp) worked man!!! thanks